# Combine Django and Bootstrap 5 Modal with Ajax

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, ajax

How to have button/link that can target object pk like a certain post with {{obj.pk}} then open a modal [edit modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RS2tG.png) and [delete modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPrxh.png).

Then the modal can edit and delete successfully without refresh using AJAX (Fetch API or Jquery). I have the problem to target the modal to open the post with certain PK. I cannot use id="editPost{{obj.id}}" or id="deletePost{{obj.id}}" to target the modal because then I need to put the modal in forloop then the modal will be repeated for each post.

Here a some of the code:

```
{% for obj in page_obj %}
                
            <li>
              <a class="dropdown-item" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editPost" href="{% url 'post-update' obj.pk %}">Edit Post</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="dropdown-item" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#deletePost" href="{% url 'post-delete' obj.pk %}">Delete Post</a>
            </li>

            <div id="post{{obj.id}}" class="box-content">
                <p class="box-text mb-2">{{ obj.content }}</p>
                <span class="username">{{ obj.username }}</span>
            </div>


{% endfor %}


            <div class="modal fade" id="deletePost" tabindex="-1">
              <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Delete Post?</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Are you sure you want to delete your post?</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="rvg-button-small" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" class="rvg-button-small">Delete</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

The way I achieve AJAX is using

```
<a class="dropdown-item" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editPost" onclick="EditPost('{{ obj.id }}')">
<a class="dropdown-item" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#deletePost" onclick="DeletePost('{{ obj.id }}')">

const DeletePost = (post_id) => {
fetch("/" + post_id + "/delete/", {
    method: "POST",
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: { "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken") },
    })
    .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            document.getElementById(`post${post_id}`).remove()
            console.log("successfully deleted")

    }).catch((e) => alert("Error deleting post."));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass arguments to your modal by using `data-<something>` as well as bootstrap does with `data-bs-<something>`.

```
<a class="dropdown-item" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#deletePost" data-object-id="{{ obj.id }}" onclick="DeletePost()">
```

Then with js, inside `DeletePost` you'll need to extract the `pk` or any other argument you pass to it. Read more about `dataset` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).

Another option is to wrap your function with an [anonymous function](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Anonymous_functions) to pass arguments to an inner one and lastly, calling the outer (anonymous) function.

In this case, I use the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) syntax but is equivalent to the regular syntax for function definitions:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#deletePost"  onclick="(() => { DeletePost({{ obj.id }}) })()">
```

I would recommend the first option as (I think) it is more flexible for future uses when you require to pass more than one argument to a function but any of them should work.

Edit:
I forgot to mention this before. If you use the first option, make sure to pass the event when calling your function in the html element in order to obtain the click target element and the dataset attached to it.

Your element should look like this:
`<a ... onclick="DeletePost(event)">`.

Your js function will receive the event as an argument:

```
const DeletePost = (event) => {
  const btn = event.target; // the clicked button.
  const object_id = btn.dataset.objectId;
  console.log(object_id); // should display the right id.
}
```

Edit 2:

In order to be able to call your Django URL within the modal:

1. Remove the `href` attribute in the `<a>` elements inside the for loop or replace the tag `<a>` for a `<button>` keeping the attributes that bootstrap needs to show your modal.
   This will prevent a premature call to your Django view without showing a modal first.
   Keep also the `data-object-id` attribute.
2. In the modal code, replace your `<button>` elements in the footer with something like this:

```
<a id="delete-post-btn" class="rvg-button-small" href="{% 'DeletePost' %}">Delete</a>
```

Keep in mind that at this stage the `href` is not complete as is missing the `object-id`.

3. Create an event listener for the modal, listening to the event ['shown.bs.modal'](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/modal/#varying-modal-content) to know when the modal is open and extract the object id to complete the `href` attribute:

```
document
  .getElementById('deletePost')
  .addEventListener('shown.bs.modal', (event) => { 

    // The modal is open and the object-id can be extracted.
    event.preventDefault(); // this step may not be needed.
    const btn = event.relatedTarget; // this is the button that contains the data-<something> attrs
    const objectId = btn.dataset.objectId; 

    // Now we add the object-id value to the href.
    const modal_btn = document.getElementById('delete-post-btn');
    modal_btn.href += String(objectId);
  })
```

Now the `href` should be complete and the button should be able to call the Django view URL with the correct object-id.

Comment: I have tried it with the first method but only get the first element of object and not the one I clicked

Comment: Please update your question adding how are you extracting the values from the dataset.

Comment: @AwesomeLerman I updated my answer with a bit more explanation on how to extract values from the dataset.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the way are success but how to make the button in the bootstrap modal(popup) be the one that delete the post? The DeletePost( ) function are currently in the dropdown-item and not the button in the modal. The modal are outside of the forloop so cannot get the object Id. How to pass the dataset value from the DeletePost function to the bootstrap modal?

Comment: Sorry , I'm Javascript newbies :/

Comment: @AwesomeLerman I updated my answer again with more details on how to achieve what you need.

Comment: Thanks again and the way is working but I'm using the Fetch API to achieve AJAX and access url. When I put the fetch API const DeletePost = ( ) => arrow function in the addEventListener shown.bs.modal, I cannot access it with onclick="DeletePost( )" because error DeletePost is not defined. How to make the delete modal button id="delete-post-btn" to execute the fetch API function when clicked?

Comment: Remove the `onclick` attribute and add a "click" listener on button id="delete-post-btn" and in the handler function run your fetch code.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping. Successfully done what I need with your help. :)

Comment: Want to ask 1 question, why the const DeletePost = ( ) => arrow function with onclick="DeletePost( )" cannot do the same things as the element.addEventListener("click") function inside the shown.bs.modal function ?

Comment: I'm glad it worked! I'm not on my PC right now but you could try passing the "event" too when you add the `onclick` attribute like this: `onclick="DeletePost(event)"`. Your function would then receive the event and with some minor tweaks to the code I wrote, I think it should work the same. In that case, the `addEventListener("click",...)` wouldn't be necessary anymore as you already have the event as a function parameter.

Comment: Currently I tweak it a bit by using JS forloop with `const deletePost = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-item"); `  `var deletePostComm = deletePost.length;` with `for (var i = 0; i < deletePostComm; i++) {
    deletePost[i].addEventListener('click')` and using `this.dataset.objectId` . Should i use the targeted event instead ?

Comment: I think it would be better if you create a new question with all the necessary code to have a better undestanding of what is your code's current state. By doing it through comments its really difficult to follow.